# Nginx doesn't show the default html page

Tags: raspberry-pi, nginx

I'm running nginx on raspberry pi.

I ran update and upgrade commands and then installed nginx.

```
1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get upgrade
3. sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Started the server

```
4. sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
```

Output

```
[ ok ] Starting nginx (via systemctl): nginx.service.
```

When I enter ip address into the browser nothing appears. What could be the problem here?

Comment: `netstat` says what?

Comment: If you found the answer to your own question, post that as an answer and accept it!

Comment: Answers should go in the Answer box, not in the Question

Answer (score 1):

Changed the root in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

from `root /var/www/html;` to `root /usr/share/nginx/www;`

I also renamed `html` folder to `www` because it was missing.

Restarted nginx for the changes to take effect.

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```